# Sending and rendering multiple images from Flask backend to Flutter frontend

Tags: python, flutter, api, flask

I've been trying to send multiple images from my flask server to flutter. I've tried everything, I either get a byte cannot be json serialised or flutter gives error in parsing the image. I've been using Image.memory() for the response.
The weird part is, if I send over one image in bytes format, it works as intended.
Any help is greatly appreciated

```
@app.route('/image', methods = ['POST'])
def hola():
  with open("1.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
  encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
  return encoded_string
```

This server side code works as intended. Following is the code I used for Flutter

```
 Future<String> uploadImage(filename, url) async {
// List<String> images;
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.files.add(
  await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('picture', filename),
);
request.headers.putIfAbsent('Connection', () => "Keep-Alive, keep-alive");
request.headers.putIfAbsent('max-age', () => '100000');
print(request.headers.entries);
http.Response response =
    await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
print("Result: ${response.statusCode}");

// print(y);
return response.body;

// return res;
```

}

Then I call this function with help of an on button click event. like this:

```
var res = await uploadImage(file.path, url);

                setState(() {
                 
                  images = res;
            
                  
                });

 Container(
          child: state == ""
              ? Text('No Image Selected')
              : Image.memory(base64.decode(images)),
        ),
```

The above is the working example it renders the Image I send. The following is where I face problem:

Server Side:

```
@app.route('/send', methods= ['GET'])
def send():
  with open("1.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
   encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
  with open("2.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
   encoded_string2 = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

  x = [str(encoded_string2), str(encoded_string)]
  return jsonify({'images':x})
```

To handle the above here is my flutter code:

```
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.files.add(
  await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('picture', filename),
);
request.headers.putIfAbsent('Connection', () => "Keep-Alive, keep-alive");
request.headers.putIfAbsent('max-age', () => '100000');
print(request.headers.entries);
http.Response response =
    await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
print("Result: ${response.statusCode}");
var x = jsonDecode(response.body);
var y = x['images'];
var z = y[0];
images = z;
```

To render the image the container code remains the same. I get this error:

```
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data
```

or I get:

```
Unexpected character at _
```

I tried parsing in a different manner, for ex:

```
var x = jsonDecode(response.body);
var y = x['images'];

var z = utf8.encode(y[0]);
images = base64Encode(x[0]);
```

or this:

```
 var x = jsonDecode(response.body);
var y = x['images'];

var z = base64Decode(y[0]);
images = z;
```

but nothing works

Comment: please include a minimal reproducible example ... its hard to understand what you are asking here

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to return several image binaries in a response I assume looks something like

`{ "image1":"content of image one bytes", "image2":"content of image two bytes" }`

and as you have found a problem arises in that binary content cannot be encoded naively into json

what you would *typically* do is convert it to base64

```
{"image1":base64.b64encode(open("my.png","rb").read()),"image2":open(...)}
```

most things can render base64 (not entirely sure specifically for flutter Images (but certainly for  tags in html)

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,<BASE64 encoded data>" />`

If not you can always get the bytes back with base64decode (which flutter almost certainly has in one of its libraries)

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that whenever I try to convert these base64 images in Flutter, I get an error saying either invalid format or unexpected character. I believe it had something to do with the casting. Since, I cannot send these images as base64 because I get an error saying byte like object isn't JSON serialiseable. So to circumvent that I typecast the base64 images into str in python itself. When I try to open these typecasted images, they will not open and the error message I get is aforementioned. I did try almost everything before asking this question here. Only sending one imagework